# compare multiple columns from multiple worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Worksheet 1 - value in column C

Worksheet 2 - value in column E

Worksheet 3 - value in column E
```

If the value in Wkst 3 = Value in Wkst 1 return "TICS"

If the value in Wkst 3 = Value in Wkst 2 return "TR"

If the value in Wkst 3 does not equal either worksheet - NONE

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but how depends on what you specifically need.  Are you comparing row by row, or if the value exists in the other two column anywhere?

Comment: comparing by columns.  If the value matches between wkst 3 and wkst 1, return ITCS; if the value matches between wkst 3 and wkst 3 return TR

Comment: comparing by columns.  If the test string matches between wkst 3 and wkst 1, return ITCS; if the text string matches between wkst 3 and wkst 3 return TR, if no match return NONE

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula(I am assuming you will start in Row2):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E2,Sheet1!C:C,0)),"TICS",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E2,Sheet2!E:E,0)),"TR","NONE"))
```

And copy down the dataset.

Comment: Thank you! Have a happy holiday!

Comment: @SBower if this worked for you then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.